# 960gs : setting border on container element which contains 2 floated grids

Tags: css, 960.gs, grid-layout

On a 960gs I'm trying to figure out which is the best/crossbrowser approach to add 1px solid border to my *wrapper-border* container which is nested into a container_12... without affecting the grid system!

```
<div class="wrapper-border">

    <div class="grid_8 alpha"></div>

    <div id="content" class="grid_4 omega"></div>

</div> <!-- end #wrapper-border -->
```

I was about to reduce the margin of both grids by -1 but it doesn't look so cool to me

Comment: Did you tried with `box-sizing: border-box;`?

Comment: adding box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; doesn't seem to have any effect! The second floated element appears below the first one

Comment: I've just added red border (5px) on container, seems ok to me. http://jsfiddle.net/S9ZYh/embedded/result/

Comment: Probably I'm missing something but wrapper-border is a container nested in container_12

Comment: Well, you didn't say so in question :)